# Understanding linear layer in sequence labeling with pytorch lstm

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to get a grip on LSTM and pytorch. Given are sequences of varying length. Every datapoint in a sequence is composed of 8 features, and every datapoint belongs to one of 6 classes (0-5). I want to learn how to use a LSTM to predict the labels of those datapoints.

So far i've made a couple of attempts to tackle this, but i fear that i miss some basic knowledge when it comes to this topic.

I've started by padding the sequences with -1 and labels to a max_amount.

I have dataloaders (train, test, val) which take care of delivering batches of shape [batch_size, max_seq_length, num_features]. The model is rather simple and consists of the lstm and a linear layer.

LSTM:

```py
...
  self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=self.sequence_dimension, # 8 features
            hidden_size=self.hidden_dim,
            num_layers=self.n_layers,
            batch_first=True,
        )
        self.linear_fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_size)
...
```

init:

```py
    def init_hidden(self):
        # the weights are of the form (nb_layers, batch_size, nb_lstm_units)
        hidden_a = torch.randn(self.n_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim)
        hidden_b = torch.randn(self.n_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim)

        hidden_a = Variable(hidden_a)
        hidden_b = Variable(hidden_b)

        return (hidden_a, hidden_b)
```

forward:

```py
     def forward(self, X):
        # shape of X: [batch_size, max_seq_len, feature_size]
       self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

        # get unpadded sequence lenghts (padding: -1)
        lenghts = []
        for batch in X:
            for i, elem in enumerate(batch):
                if elem[0] == -1:
                    lenghts.append(i-1)
                    break

        # pack the padded sequences, length contains unpadded lenghts (eg., [43,46,67,121]
        x_packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(X, lenghts, batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)

        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(x_packed.float(), self.hidden)

        # unpack
        x_unpacked, seq_len = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(lstm_out, batch_first=True)

        #squash the batches from [batch_size, max_seq_len_of_this_batch, hidden_dim]
        #to [batch_size*max_seq_len_of_this_batch, hidden dim]
        batches_squashed = x_unpacked.contiguous().view(-1, x_unpacked.shape[2])

        #feed it to linear
        y_pred = self.linear_fc(batches_squashed)

        #unsquash batches to [batch_size, max_seq_len_of_this_batch, hidden_dim]
        y_pred = y_pred.contiguous().view((batch_size, max(lenghts),self.output_size))
        return y_pred, max(lenghts)
```

I'm very unsure if i do this correctly, especially with the linear layer. It receives a tensor of shape [batchsize*max_seq_len, hidden_layers], is that correct? There are still padded values in there...

In my train loop i simply init the hidden state for every epoch and then loop over (input, labels) from the dataloader:

```py
    loss_funtion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=-1)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
```

```py
   for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        counter+=1
        net.zero_grad()
        if train_on_gpu:
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

        output, _ = net(inputs)

        #remove excessive padding for labels
        labels = decreasing_padding(labels, max_padding_for_this_batch)

        #transposing the output to fit the crossEntropy definiton
        loss = loss_funtion(output.transpose(1, 2),labels.long())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

The LSTM often just outputs a single label for the whole sequence (there are sequences for which this is correct). Loss and accurracy on train and validation set indicate that it is not learning. While the loss decreases slightly it fluctuates highly.

I suspect the linear layer to be implemented incorrectly.

- Should i pass every hidden state (without padding?) one by one through the layer and stack its outputs?

I would be tremendously grateful if someone could point out my mistakes and misconceptions, i've spent quite some time with this so far.

Comment: The question, as is, won't receive much attention, I think. It seems to be too broad. Can you narrow down to a specific problem and ask this one specific question more clearly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are right. I edited my question accordingly. :)